# Applescript to change illustrator colors

Tags: applescript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to change a colour in an illustrator document from one color the another heres what i've got but it keeps saying "can't find color" i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong?

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"

          if exists color is equal to "C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=90" then

                    set color to "C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=100"

          end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set allMyItems to every path item of current document whose fill color is {cyan:0.0, magenta:0.0, yellow:0.0, black:90.0}
    repeat with myItem in allMyItems
        set fill color of myItem to {cyan:0.0, magenta:0.0, yellow:0.0, black:100.0}
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it cant understand what exactly color are you setting (i.e. fill color, stroke color, etc.). Or if you just setting a variable named 'color' than you probably need to choose another name (something like myColor) because this one is reserved